# How to download 100 images at a time with gtm-http-fetcher?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

I'm using gtm-http-fetcher in my application. It's easy to fetch a single resource with it. Now I need to download 100 pictures at a time. I have the URL for each image. When I get a image, I need to match it with its URL. What should I do?

**UPDATE:**
May I put all the fetchers into an operation queue to fetch images concurrently?

Comment: I could tell you with ASIHTTPRequest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL is available as

```
  NSURL *url = fetcher.mutableRequest.URL;
```

Comment: The fetcher provides the method setProperty:forKey: and the property userData for passing values to the callbacks.The fetch request is available in the mutableRequest property.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a dictionary and map the connection object to the url

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionary];  //you'll need to retain this
...
[dict setObject:thisUrl forKey:thisConnection];
```

Then get the urls out when you need them when the connection finished loading

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
...
     NSURL *url = [dict objectForKey:thisConnection]
```